# how to host webpage through shell script in windows

Tags: python, windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i am trying to host a Webpage locally through .sh file(batch Script) in windows 10 . acutally this all stuff are under python project in pycharm,let me show the structure

```
tree -A
.
├── guiscrape.py
├── scrape.py
└── simple_server
  ├── img
  │ ├── owl-alcohol.png
  │ ├── owl-book.png
  │ ├── owl-books.png
  │ ├── owl-ebook.jpg
  │ └── owl-rose.jpeg
  ├── index.html
  └── serve.sh
```

here 'tree' is the python project root directory in which there are two python file(scrape.py,guiscrape.py). 'simple_server' is a folder contain webpage(index.html),'img' folder and 'serve.sh'(batch script).

now i have a instruction to just add command($ ./serve.sh) in serve.sh and run it. but on doing it shows an error

error:Executable is not specified

please tell me what's wrong and what could be done.

i just want to host webpage locally through batch script using python

Comment: You mean you are using BASH within the Linux Subsystem on Windows 10.  So you should be using the bash tag, not the batch-file tag.

Comment: what is `serve.sh` ?  Never heard of it.